# Why is my while loop continuing even after the condition is met

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am trying to create a simple game where you can attack or defend. I created two attack functions (player and enemy) and a while loop with the condition of ending when either health ends up at 0, but when I run the program, the while loops repeats even after one of the health's is less than 0.

```
while playerHealth > 0 or enemyHealth > 0:
    choice = input("Attack(a) or defend(d)?")
    if choice == "a":
        playerAttack()
    elif choice == "d":
        print("Defend")
    else:
        print("ERROR")
    time.sleep(3)
    enemyAttack()

if playerHealth <= 0:
    print("Game over")

if enemyHealth <= 0:
    print("You win!")
```

I expect the while loop to repeat until the enemy or player's health reacher 0, then show either game over or you win depending on whose health runs out first. 
The actual result is the game goes slightly past when it should end and the health is well below 0.

Comment: There is no while loop in your code

Comment: Where is the loop?

Comment: Please add the minimal working example of your problem and the expected output.

Comment: neither your `playerHealth` nor your `enemyHealth` change within the loop. so if you enter the `while` loop it will never stop. (i assume you did not declare those variables `global` in any of your functions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
while playerHealth > 0 and enemyHealth > 0:
```

instead of the `or`.

The way you have your conditional now, the game will not stop until *both* health bars are 0 or less. So if you enemy has already been beaten, but your player has more than 0 health, the game will keep running.

Comment: @ewhiting Or means the loop will continue if either condition is met.

Comment: @lc74 ah.. I was losing my mind

Comment: I did that and now when the player runs out of health the game stops, however if the enemy runs out of health first, it does another attack and the game ends with a game over and a you win because both of the health's are below 0

Comment: @windstorm2002 thats because you always do an enemy attack. You should only do one or the other. Alternatively you can add a `break`.